# Snowflake schema causing multiple rows

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

I'm creating a data warehouse and we have company -> Sectors -> Org

I have created three dimension

```
   Table Company 
       CompanyKey  Company ID  CompanyName
         1              1.1          ABC
         2              2.1          XYZ

   Table Sector
        SectorKey     SectorID  SectorName  Company Key
          1             1          MNQ          1
          2             1          MNQ          2
```

Because some sectors are shared across company.

This is causing Duplication withing my Org Dimension Table and Fact table.

Is their a way I can generate the Sector Key only when Sector name changes and not on each row.

Comment: Then your `Sector` table would not have a primary key . . . and that seems like a really bad thing.

Comment: I am breaking a table Called Organization into Company ,Sector & Org as three dimension so we have a separate dimension for Company,Sector & Org  because Different Department report at different levels.HR has reports at company level and Finance goes to Org level and other till sector Level.

Comment: Please help Any suggestion ..Should I make a mapping table between Company Sector & Org and along with Three dimension Company ,Sector And Org .So the dimension tables does have duplicate names .